# How to combine two search bars with unobtrusive validation into one

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, unobtrusive-validation

I have a C#/.Net Framework 4.7.2 application with two search bars that have different controllers, models, and **different** validation based on unobtrusive-validation. The users asked if I can combine those two search bars into one:

Currently, the search bars look like this:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

...when you click the opposite type search, it changes to...

[image]

To create a quick prototype of how it might look like, I did the following:

- Moved the second bar below the first one, made both bars look the same in terms of shape, and made the second bar hidden by default
- Added to both bars radio-buttons that switch between search modes
- Added JS logic that changes the search bars in the following fashion when toggle button is clicked:

  - Hide the current search bar and show the opposite bar
  - Copy the value from the current bar to the opposite bar
  - Focus the opposite bar that is visible now
  - Manipulate the radiobutton on the visible bar so it represents the correct bar

```
$(window).load(function() {   
  const documentSearchBar = $("#filing-search");
  const generalSearchBar = $("#general-search");

  const generalSearchButton1 = $("#general-search-button1");
  const generalSearchButton2 = $("#general-search-button2");
  const documentSearchButton1 = $("#document-search-button1");
  const documentSearchButton2 = $("#document-search-button2");

  const searchRadioButtons1 = $("input[name='search-button-choice1']");
  const searchRadioButtons2 = $("input[name='search-button-choice2']");

  const generalSearchInput = $("#Text");
  const documentSearchInput = $("#document-search-input");

  searchRadioButtons1.change(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id === "document-search-button1") {
      documentSearchInput.val(generalSearchInput.val());
      generalSearchInput.val("");
      documentSearchBar.show();
      generalSearchBar.hide();
      generalSearchButton1.prop("checked", true);
      documentSearchInput.focus();
    } else if (event.target.id === "general-search-button1") {
      generalSearchInput.val(documentSearchInput.val());
      documentSearchInput.val("");
      documentSearchBar.hide();
      generalSearchBar.show();
      documentSearchButton1.prop("checked", true);
      generalSearchInput.focus();
    }
  });

  searchRadioButtons2.change(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id === "document-search-button2") {
      documentSearchInput.val(generalSearchInput.val());
      generalSearchInput.val("");
      documentSearchBar.show();
      generalSearchBar.hide();
      generalSearchButton2.prop("checked", true);
      documentSearchInput.focus();
    } else if (event.target.id === "general-search-button2") {
      generalSearchInput.val(documentSearchInput.val());
      documentSearchInput.val("");
      documentSearchBar.hide();
      generalSearchBar.show();
      documentSearchButton2.prop("checked", true);
      generalSearchInput.focus();
    }
  });  
});
```

While this solution works for demonstration purposes, it's a quick hack and now I am thinking on how I can use **only one bar** instead of two (and hiding one of them), but switch the unobtrusive validation on the front end with JS.

In other words, **is there a way to reuse the same form for two types of input with different validation and switch between those on the front-end with JS?**

---

Just in case it's relevant, here is the model for General Search:

```
 public class HomeViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "SearchRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "SearchByKeyword")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessageResourceName = "AtLeast3Characters", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Max250Characters", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "ExcludeReceipts")]
        public bool ExcludeReceipts { get; set; }
    }
```

Model for searching by Document ID:

```
    public class FilingIdViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FilingIdRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "FilingIdSearch")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(^|, )(([A-Za-z]\d{5})|([A-Za-z]\d{5}[-][0-9]+)|([A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\d[A-Za-z]\d))$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "FilingIdFormat", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonably clear question. Initially it looks like a Bootstrap or a JS question to readers, but in fact when one gets into the detail it is a C# framework question (that was my confusion anyway - I should have looked at the tags!). That may be why it has not received answers yet.

Comment: For your existing design, are you using HTML forms (with a traditional-style browser round trip) or an AJAX operation? It seems to me that your server-side logic needs to select the right model in order to perform the search - it must do that already, and your adjustment needs to select it based on the radio icon value rather than form action URL.

Comment: I suspect there is enough detail here for a .net person to answer, but if you still do not get attention despite the upvote, ping me here and I will add a bounty.

Comment: Currently, as a prototype, I modified both search bars by adding the radio buttons for them. Then I changed both search bars visually so they look the same, and hid the second one initially. When the user changes the search mode, I dynamically (with JS) hide the general search bar, show the document search bar, copy the value from the first bar’s input, insert it to the second bar’s input, focus the second bar’s input, and manipulate the radio button.

Comment: The idea is that the change is transparent for user, the user does not notice that there are actually two search bar, everything works seamlessly, the user does not know that there are in fact two search bars. Also, the backend-provided validation works for both search bars.

Comment: Now, why would I do this abomination? :) The main idea here is to retain the validation rules that are set on the back-end in the models are retained on the front end. So if you change those rules in the future in the back-end, you do not need to change the front-end validation, it’s the same effectively.

Comment: Now, the second option is to create a single search bar, create custom validation rules (that are not provided by the back end from the model into the unobtrusive validation on the front end), and change the validation rules based on the user selection of the search mode (manipulating the radio buttons). This is way cleaner approach and more accessibility friendly. However, with this option, if the back-end validation rules on models are changed, one has to change the front-end validation separately, so I do not like this option either.